# select only one row in sum and group

Tags: sql, join, group-by

i have a table **TB_Orders** , i save orders in thatl ,ike below :

| userid | factorid | productname | economy | vip | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A-123 | name1 | 13000 | 18000 | 3 |
| 1 | A-123 | name2 | 9000 | 13000 | 4 |
| 2 | A-124 | name2 | 2000 | 5000 | 2 |

For example, user 1: has registered two orders with invoice number A-123.

And user 2 has only registered one order

I want to report as follows:

| userid | factorid | total economy | total vip | total count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A-123 | 21000 | 31000 | 7 |
| 2 | A-124 | 2000 | 5000 | 2 |

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is an aggregation query:

```
select userid, factorid, sum(economy), sum(vip), sum(count)
from tb_orders
group by userid, factorid;
```

Aggregation is a very basic part of SQL functionality.  If you don't recognize it, I would suggest that you brush up on your SQL skills with a tutorial, book, or something like that.